# Invalid use of property compile error

Tags: vba, compilation

I am getting the invalid use of property compile error right off the bat. any ideas?  This code is part of a project to capture change management info.

```
 Sub New_Process(target As Range)

     Dim vNewRng As Range, vOldRng As Range, r As Range
     Set vNewRng = target

     Application.Undo

     Set vOldRng = Range(vNewRng.Address())

     For Each r In vOldRng
         r.Value
     Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`r.Value` should be something meaningful.

E.g. `r.Value = r.Value`
or `r.Value = "vityata"`

Comment: i got so caught up in thinking it was a "target" issue, I missed the obvious answer, thank you.

Comment: @mpmcderm - I was also thinking about it, until I decided to check it myself. :)